# the DatePicker widget does take into account the [disabled] parameter

Tags: datepicker, vmware-clarity, disabled-control

Although all form controls react perfectly to the [disabled] parameter, the DatePicker doesn't. This is a real shame

Comment: Can you provide an example for what you are seeing? Starter stackblitz was are here: https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: There was also a bug fixed recently with disabled not working as expected in some uses. Please help us with a reproduction, but it should work or its a bug to file.